# white space in the right side rendering issues (opera and safari)

Tags: css, html

hi can someone know why `opera` and `safari` have extra white space in the `right` when i use percentage in my width. below is my code:

`safari 5.1` and `opera 11.11`

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/YP8N9/1/)

html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">

<head>
  <title>sample</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />

</head>

<body>

    <div class="wrap">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
    html, body, div, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, ul, ol, dl, li, dt, dd, p, blockquote, pre, form, fieldset, table, th, td, img  {
  margin: 0; padding: 0
}

/* remember to define focus styles! */
:focus {
    outline: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size:13px;
  color:#fff;
  background-color:#000;

}

a {color:#444; text-decoration:none;}

ul li {list-style-type:none;}

p {padding:0 0 1.5em 0; line-height:1.7em; float:left;}

img {border:none}


.wrap {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
}
.wrap div{
    float:left;
    width:25%;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#222;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Using your example code [gives me a document with white-space on every side](http://jsfiddle.net/FgaBE/embedded/result/)... Could you post your full HTML/CSS?

Comment: Is the CSS code in your post everything that's in `style.css`?

Comment: Well judging by your HTML/CSS you simply haven't [reset your CSS](http://cssreset.com)

Comment: used to css reset as like this html,body,div,.wrap{margin:0;padding:0;}

Comment: Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sVvhy/ please modify and include it in your post to make it easier to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this CSS:

```
body {
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Adding this in my css problem is still there.

Comment: There's no white space on Safari for me with the code that you just updated. Also, you can use a wildcard instead of listing all of those tags - `*{margin:0px;padding:0px;}`

Comment: i have safari 5.1 and opera 11.11

Answer (score 0):

Cool! Seems Safari is calculating terribly wrong. You can see it sometimes fits if you resize the frame. No idea what's going on. However, a possible workaround would be `display: table`:

```
.wrap {
    width:100%;
    display: table;
}

.wrap div{
    width:25%;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#222;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

[Here is a demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/YP8N9/3/)

This may not be possible in your situation, don't know. But it solves the wrong calculation problem.